# how to use windbg to break into directx application process?

Tags: directx, windbg

I run the DirectX SDK sample, BasicHLSL10 and use a Windbg to attach to the process.
After breaking into the process, I use 'x d3d*!*Render' and 'x dxgi!*' to list the functions I am interested.
I then set breakpoints on 'dxgi!D3DKMTPresent' as well as all the 'd3d*!D3DKMTRender'.
After that I hit 'g' for the process to continue.
However, BasicHLSL10 seems to continue running without stepping on those breakpoints.
I'm thinking this could be one of those COM Interface thing, but I'm not very familiar. How, can I break into the process when it is calling some of the DirectX call?
Will this technique also works on media players that uses DXVA?

Answer (score 0):

looks like it could be because D3DKMT* functions are only use by OpenGL Installable Client Driver (at least that is what I think I read in WDK), so maybe that is why BasicHLSL10 never use it...